# Best way to parse requested URL in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a URL like:

`http://www.something.com/project/edit/`**987654321**

What's the best way to parse the **987654321** part of the URL using AngularJS? Are there any helper functions within Angular? (I'd prefer to not use jQuery)

If I understand it correctly, the routing functions within AngularJS won't work unless you use a # within the URL or enabled HTML5 mode.

We need to parse this URL when the page is first loaded.

Comment: what do you mean by parse?

Comment: Use document.URL and parse with regex or substring/indexOf

Comment: Investigate the $location service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`$location` service's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) `$location#path()` function:

```
# given: url = http://www.something.com/project/edit/987654321
$location.path().split('/').pop();
```

**However**, it sounds like you have a routing issue.  Check out the [Angular Tutorial on Routing](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07), which shows how to correctly use `$routeProvider` routes in your `app.js` configuration.  From the tutorial:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
       when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise( ...)  //omitting remainder of cut/paste
```

So your `app.js` would have a route definition like:

```
ender2050App.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/project/edit/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/editor.html',
        controller: 'EditorCtrl'
      })
```

And your controller file (i.e., controllers.js) would have the `EditorCtrl` that injects the `$routeParams` service to access the `id` variable.

If you need a more customized parsing option, check out the [`$parse` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).

Answer (score 11):

I'll answer the question based on the title because I landed here looking for a way to parse a url as well. Here's the [answer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjisPHJhqrKAhWCST4KHYypB64QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FPT5BG%2F4%2F&usg=AFQjCNGAttMNWWCr8g4UxcQnnVeAta0oqQ&sig2=JJfU76cw9Knqm7LftFrH7Q) I found on a fiddler page.

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://www.example.com";
//At this point it's parsed and all the info is on the parser object
console.log(parser.protocol);
console.log(parser.hash);
console.log(parser.hostname);
console.log(parser.port);
console.log(parser.pathname);
console.log(parser.search);
```

[Update]
I just noticed there's a URL class.

```
var parsedURL = new URL('http://www.example.com');
console.log(parsedURL.hash);
console.log(parsedURL.protocol);
console.log(parsedURL.host);
//etc
```

Comment: Thanks, I never used the URL class.

Comment: URL is not supported at all in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Both the question AND the answer don't respect the title. I landed here trying to search *how to parse ANY url* in angular. This question is about parsing the **requested** url. What if I want to parse `http://www.google.com` ??

Edited it.

Comment: Good point but this would be better as a comment, instead of being posted as an answer.

Comment: If you look at the Update in my answer you'll see how to parse any URL. Even the first part of the answer would do it.