# angular - how can I parse query parameters from a standalone string

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm aware that I can parse the query string parameters in the browser url using $location.search(), however does angular expose any service to do this manually?

I mean lets say I have the string "www.example.com/my/route?p1=boom&p2=bam"

Does angular give me a way to parse the query string out of it, just like it does internally?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798351/1543596) answer.
You can use Url class in js and did something like this:

```
var url = new URL("http://www.google.com?query=aaaaa");
console.log(url.search)
```

You will get output
`?query=aaaaa`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly...
This would give you your query string. Hope it helps.

```
app.controller('queryController', function($scope, $routeParams){
    $scope.result = $routeParams.p1 + $routeParams.p2;
})
```

Comment: No, I want to parse it from a string not from the browser url bar.

Comment: Ah.. ok, aside from just writing the algo, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [UrlSerializer](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer)

Example :

```
... myClass {

constructor(private urlSerializer) { }

... myFunc(urlInString: string): void {
  const myParsedUrl = this.urlSerializer.parse(urlInString);
  // Use myParsedUrl, for example :
  // myParsedUrl.queryParams...
}
```